# Handlebars not populating data after first space in input field

Tags: html, input, handlebars.js

```
    {{#if data.project_name}}
        <h1>{{data.project_name}}</h1>
    {{/if}}
```

shows "This is the value" (data.project_name == "This is the value") correctly inside the h1 tag, but

```
    {{#if data.project_name}}
         <input type="text" value={{data.project_name}}>
    {{/if}}
```

shows only "This" inside the input, please help...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it, a friend told what the problem was

```
    <input type="text" value="{{data.project_name}}">
```

when I wasn't putting quotes, the handlebars was taking only "
This" as the value attributes's value, and discarding the rest of the string, though I don't know why is it.

***EDIT***

and I also found a closed issue on handlebars issues on github : https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1474